# CSS Style Double Border

Tags: html, css, border

I was styling and got an idea how to design my website, but I didn't know how to do it, tried search a lot, but didn't find anything helpful, so I hope you guys can help me a bit.

There's my idea, I was using `border: 10px double cyan`, but there's a space in the middle which inherit background color. So is there any way to set color of the middle?

Comment: You can use `box-shadow` this way: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ChenBri/pen/yLjdOaJ)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with background like below:

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  border: 20px double cyan;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) padding-box, /* main background */
   blue; /* color between double border */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```